# Testing package-index form

Tags: discussion

I'm building an index of packages (well, package location) as an `EntityStore` and made a `FormFunction` that will dump to the `CloudObject` it's stored in.

Currently I'm looking for people to try it out and to get design feedback (feel free to chime in even if just to say you think this is a terrible idea).

If anyone is interested the form is below. It should be public but do inform me if it isn't and I'll make it so.

https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-13f6055a-bf2f-4f56-b49e-4e7b72430c04/PackageIndex/submit

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where/how can the entity store be downloaded?

Comment: @C.E. I was gonna wait for other people to actually submit info to it, but it'll be downloadble from https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-13f6055a-bf2f-4f56-b49e-4e7b72430c04/PackageIndex/EntityStore.mx. I have a package that will download that automatically at load-time and provide and interface to the EntityStore which I'll put up once it's more complete.